# Python: all possible words (permutations) of fixed length in mini-alphabet

Tags: algorithm, permutation

Let's say I have a string like so:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]\:;"'?/>.<,`~|€
```

This is basicly a list of all the characters on my keyboard. How could I get all possible combinations for, let's say, a "word" made up of 8 of these chars? I know there are going to be millions of possibilities.

Cheers!

Comment: What you are describing is called a `permutation`.  That would be key in finding additional resources on the internet to assist.

Comment: More than millions, more than billions. It's 500,000,000,000,000 combinations, give or take a hundred thousand billion or two. If it took you a millisecond to process each string it'd take you 20 years to process all that data. Have you thought this through?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate all permutations of a list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: @George: No, a permutation is a reordering of all the 69 characters. This is a quite different thing than *8-character words made out of some of these 69 characters*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Difference between permutations and combinations**

You are either looking for a permutation or a combination.

`'abc'` and `'bac'` are different permutations, but they are the same combination `{a,b,c}`.

Permutations of 'abc': `''`, `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'ab'`, `'ba'`, `'ac'`, `'ca'`, `'bc'`, `'cb'`, `'abc'`, `'acb'`, `'bac'`, `'bca'`, `'cab'`, `'cba'`

Combinations of 'abc': `{}`, `{'a'}`, `{'b'}`, `{'c'}`, `{'a','b'}`, `{'b','c'}`, `{'a','c'}`, `{'a','b','c'}`

---

**In python**

Use `from itertools import *` (since the functions there really should be in the default namespace), or `import itertools` if you'd like.

If you care about **permutations**:

```
permutations(yourString, 8)
```

If you care about **combinations** :

```
combinations(yourString, 8)
```

---

**In other languages**

In other languages, there are simple recursive or iterative algorithms to generate these. See wikipedia or stackoverflow. e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Systematic_generation_of_all_permutations

---

**Important note**

Do note that the number of permutations is `N!`, so for example your string would have

- `(69 choose 8) = 8 billion` *combinations* of length 8, and therefore...
- `(69 choose 8) * 8! ~= 3.37 × 10^14` *permutations* of length 8.

You'll run out of memory if you are storing every permutation. Even if you don't (because you're reducing them), it'll take a long time to run, maybe somewhere between 1-10 days on a modern computer.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! And thanks to @George as well. Permutations is what I'm looking for. However, is there a way I can run permutations, but "stop" once I've reached a certain number - so to store the information in a database, clear the RAM, and start from where I left off?

Comment: @Judge: yes, these are generators, and thus you can use them in a for loop, like `for p in permutations(...):` without having to worry that you will use up all your memory. Do note that the number of permutations is `N!`, so for example your string would have `(69 choose 8) * 8! ~= 3.37 × 10^14` permutations. You'll run out of memory if you are storing every permutation. Even if you aren't, it'll take a long time to run, maybe somewhere between 1-10 days on a modern computer. **edited because previous math was wrong**